# docker trust command gives "No signatures or cannot access prod.organization.dtr.com" for an image which already exist

Tags: windows, macos, docker, containers, dtr

Docker trust is throwing an error for the following command, when in fact the image exists and I can even pull it with no issues:

```
docker trust inspect ourcompanydtr.com/dev/tool:april12
```

And the error I am getting is this one:

```
No signatures or cannot access ourcompanydtr.com/dev/tool:april12
```

Notice that I did not have this issue when I was running it on windows, but recently I moved to MAC and since then, that is the only command not working for me.

All my coworkers with windows machines are able to get the correct results back. I also put all the certificates inside the keychain but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: guess no one has seen this issue before?

Comment: Did you try accessing this URL from your Mac (ping or browser) ?